# How can I set a node's nested (address field) value in a custom submit handler?

Tags: forms

I need to clear any data from an address field's values (administrative area, etc.)

In my custom submit hanlder for node form, I know I can use something like below for a standard field:

```
<?php
  $form_state->setValue('field_alternate_phone', [['value' => 'NEW VALUE']]);
?>
```

But I cannot figure out how to change the value of a nested address field where the values are something like:

[image]

I've solutions similar to below but nothing is working:

```
$form_state->setValue('field_service_location', [
    ['address' => ['organization' => 'test22111']]
  ]);
```

Comment: Have you tried with `$form_state->setValue(['field_service_location'][0]['address']['organization'], 'your value here')`. As pointed in the documentation, the key for `setValue` could be either a string for a direct field or an array for nested field. Reference here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AsetValue/8.7.x